# DRUPAL, Views: exposed filter.. how can I unselect all tags?

Tags: drupal, drupal-views, drupal-taxonomy

I'm using Drupal, Views, tag exposed filter and I would like to allow my customer to select the default tags from back-end. However when he selects some tags is not possible anymore to unselect all of them.

See initial picture: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/72686/Picture%201.png

Now all the tags are unselected, but if I select just one of them, then I cannot anymore come back to the initial configuration. (at least one tag remains selected).

How can I fix this ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the Default view, and someone overrides child views, it no longer uses the default settings. However, if they don't click on 'Override' when changing a view setting type, it will apply those changes to that view **and** the default view.

You have to setup the views, and he makes the choice what tags to select. It sounds like you two are overwriting each other in the view filter options. When you create a child view and change its configuration, be sure to click 'Override' in the top right corner of the option that appears. This will let you override that views settings, and not alter the initial default settings.

Also, you probably know this, but if you ctrl click it should unselect one that is selected.